# Select where like is not working, throwing an error message 207

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to query the database from Visual Studio 2017 using T-SQL. The query is:

```
Select * 
From table 
Where columnname like '0%'
```

The error message is as follows:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '0%'.

The like clause is greyed in the console for some reason, it is not blue like the others.

I would like to get all records whose byte starts with 0 eg:

```
SELECT JobFileName 
FROM JobImages 
WHERE JobFileName LIKE "0%"
```

Comment: The edit done to the question has hidden the fact that the original query had double quotes, which was the cause of the error.

Comment: This is not necessarily a typo error. **The exact same query will work in SQL Server under specific conditions**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server with [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the double quotes are used to delimit identifiers (database, column and table names etc). Use single quotes to delimit strings - this works regardless of `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` setting:

```
SELECT JobFileName FROM JobImages WHERE JobFileName LIKE '0%'
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrong quotes. Double quotes "0%" are used to wrap column names.

Use a single quote '0%' instead